# Definite Integral of Polynomial of Sine and Cosines

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I was wondering if there is a way to compute definite integral 
\begin{align}
I(m,n) :=\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^m (\theta) \cdot \cos^{n}(\theta) \ \mathrm{d} \theta
\end{align}
in general for integer-valued $m$ and $n$. This problem arises when I try to compute integrals of trigonometric functions over a high dimensional sphere.

In fact I am more interested in the asymptotic order of this integral. I was wondering how $I(m,n)$ behaves when $n$ goes to infinity. For example, what is the limit of $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} I(2, n)$?

Comment: With certain substitutions you can express this integral in terms of beta function which is then easily evaluated by its relation to gamma. Alteratively you can find reccurence relations for such integrals by integration by parts and trygonometrii substitutions.

Comment: You could have used Walli's formula if the upper limit was $\pi$/2

Comment: The indefinite integral is described [on this page](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/powerproduct/powerproduct.html). And of course from the indefinite integral you can get the definite integral.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try to expand 
$$\cos^n(x) = \frac{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^n}{2^n} = \frac{e^{-inx}(e^{2ix}+1)^n}{2^n} = \frac{e^{-inx}}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} e^{2ikx}$$
$$\sin^m(x) = \frac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^m}{(2i)^m} = \frac{e^{-imx}(e^{2ix}-1)^m}{(2i)^m} = (-1)^m\frac{e^{-imx}}{(2i)^m}\sum_{l=0}^m {m\choose l} (-1)^l e^{2ilx}$$

$$\cos^n(x) \sin^m(x) =\frac{(-1)^m}{2^{n+m}i^m}\sum_{l=0}^m \sum_{k=0}^n {m\choose l} {n\choose k} (-1)^l e^{\textstyle i(2l+2k-n-m)x}  $$

for $a \in \mathbb{Z}^*$ we know that $\int_0^\pi e^{2 i a x} dx = 0$ so that

$$\int_0^\pi \sin^m(x) \cos^n(x) dx = \pi \frac{(-1)^m}{2^{n+m}i^m}\sum_{(l,k) \in E_{n,m}} {m\choose l} {n\choose k} (-1)^l $$

where $E_{n,m} = \left\{ (l,k) \ | \ 2l+2k=n+m, l \in \{0 \ldots m\}, k \in \{0 \ldots n\} \right\}$

this also tells us that the result is non-zero only when $m$ and $n$ are even (if $m$ is odd the result is imaginary and if $m+n$ is odd $E_{n,m}$ is empty)

Comment: This looks interesting. Is it possible to apply this method to study the asymptotic setting where $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

When at least one of the exponents is odd, substitute $\sin^2 x = (1 - \cos^2 x)$ and $\cos^2 x = (1 - \sin^2 x)$ as in:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \sin^3 x \cos ^4 x \, \textrm{d}x &=& \int \sin^2 x \cos^4 x(\sin x \, \textrm{d}x) \\
 &=& \int (1 - \cos^2 x) cos^4 x (\sin x \, \textrm{d}x) \\
 &=& \int \cos ^4 x \sin x \, \textrm{d}x - \int \cos^6 x \sin x \, \textrm{d}x \\
 &=& \frac{-\cos^5 x}{5} + \frac{\cos^7 x}{7} + C \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

When both $m$ and $n$ are even, substitute $\sin^2 x = \frac{1 - \cos 2x}{2}$ and $\cos^2 x = \frac{1 + \cos 2x}{2}$ as in:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \sin^2 x \cos^4 x \, \textrm{d}x &=& \int \left(\frac{1 - \cos 2x}{2}\right) \left(\frac{1 + \cos 2x}{2}\right)^2 \, \textrm{d}x \\
 &=& \frac{1}{8} \int \, \textrm{d}x + \frac{1}{8} \int \cos 2x \, \textrm{d}x - \frac{1}{8} \int \cos^2 2x \, \textrm{d}x - \frac{1}{8} \int \cos^3 2x \, \textrm{d}x \\
 &=& \frac{x}{8} + \frac{1}{16} \sin 2x - \frac{1}{8} \int \frac{1 + \cos 4x}{2} \, \textrm{d}x - \frac{1}{8} \int (1 - \sin^2 2x) \cos 2x \, \textrm{d}x \\
 && ... \\
 &=& \frac{x}{16} + \frac{\sin^3 2x}{48} - \frac{\sin 4x}{64} + C
\end{eqnarray}
$$

This requires computing the indefinite integral on which to apply your interval, which might be painful for high values of $m$ or $n$. I hope someone has a better answer.